# How to get Toolbar to overlay sibling layout (z-ordering)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, android-toolbar, z-order

For the life of me, I cannot get this `Toolbar` to layout on top (note: not above, but on top of) its sibling `LinearLayout`. The only way I can get the `Toolbar` to overlay its sibling is by specifying the `Toolbar`'s elevation to be  > 0, but this doesn't work for pre-5.0.

I am using a parent `FrameLayout`, and the child `Toolbar` is located after its sibling `LinearLayout` in the XML. What am I missing? Even the Android Studio preview pane shows the `Toolbar` on top of the `LinearLayout`

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_container"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:id="@+id/home_list_listview"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/home_list_item"
            >
        </ListView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/slogan"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a fragment committing the linear layout over the main activity, which already contained it. Oops!

Answer (score 0):

That's because of FrameLayout. 
If you want to use FrameLayout, the views will not relate each other.
So all you need to do is ...

```
set "height of toolbar" to MarginTop of LinearLayout.
```

Hope, it will help.